# maven dependency check failure when cleaning and installing project

Tags: maven, owasp

**strong text**
my build fails when i perform a maven clean install:

i have the following error:

Failed to execute goal org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:5.3.2:check (default) on project

[ERROR] bcpg-jdk15on-1.56.jar: CVE-2005-0366
[ERROR] cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar\META-INF/maven/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/pom.xml: CVE-2017-7957, CVE-2016-3674

is there a command to not to fail on error ,tahnks

Answer (score 0):

I would set `<failOnError>` on false in the configuration of the dependency check maven plugin.

Comment: yes i used this command that works too: -Pdev -Ddependency-check.skip=true